# Write Error in WordPress

Tags: xampp

I have a website on localhost. When I open the site, it shows a white screen which says just the following text,
"write error."
What could be wrong? Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions settings of your folders?

Comment: @Aravona: I just checked wp-contents folder. Its read only.

Comment: Try changing that folder to 755?

Comment: I am using Windows. Can you please guide how can I do it in Windows 10? Thanks.